# How can I find the yaw/pitch to point towards a 3D vector in java?

Tags: java, rotation

I am creating a mod for minecraft, however I figured it'd be best to ask out of the context of it since I'm not using forge which basically makes a lot of the code need bare bones java.

Some context is needed, because of what is used from minecraft, which I will explain now.

Minecraft displays pitch in a range of -90 to 90, not 0 to 180, which is why values are sometimes modified by adding or subtracting. Also, there is a function used in my functions, which is `getNeededRotations()`, only context needed to understand that should be the getEyesPos(), returns a vector of the camera position, self explanatory.

```java
public static Rotation getNeededRotations(Vec3 vec)
    {
        Vec3 eyesPos = getEyesPos();
        
        double diffX = vec.xCoord - eyesPos.xCoord;
        double diffY = vec.yCoord - eyesPos.yCoord;
        double diffZ = vec.zCoord - eyesPos.zCoord;
        
        double diffXZ = Math.sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffZ * diffZ);
        
        float yaw = (float)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(diffZ, diffX)) - 90F;
        float pitch = (float)-Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(diffY, diffXZ));
        
        return new Rotation(yaw, pitch);
    }
```

I have tried making this myself, by researching the math needed, however it resulted in some very strange rotations, so I decided to scrap it. I referenced and used some functions from a public github repository. I created a function to return the yaw, which works great, which is below:

```java
public static double getYawToLookVec(Vec3 vec)
    {
        Rotation needed = getNeededRotations(vec);
        
        EntityPlayerSP player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer;
        float currentYaw = MathHelper.wrapAngleTo180_float(player.cameraYaw);
        
        float diffYaw = currentYaw - needed.yaw;
        
        return -diffYaw;
    }
```

But pitch is my problem, I figured I'd do the same thing, since that worked fine, but that is not the case, it resulted in strange behavior and rapid turning. I messed with my variables, until I reached this:

```java
public static double getPitchToLookVec(Vec3 vec)
    {
        Rotation needed = getNeededRotations(vec);
        
        EntityPlayerSP player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer;
        float currentPitch = MathHelper.wrapAngleTo180_float(player.rotationPitch);
        
        float diffPitch = currentPitch - needed.pitch;
        
        
        return -(diffPitch + 90);
    }
```

At first, this seems like a very good step in the right direction, which it was, but it acts very strange when used, for some reason, every other time the function is used, it seems to return what is the desired pitch, but negated, so one use it returns about 45, the next time it returns -45, which results in an odd flickering motion. As you can see from this data, that is what happens (pitch)

```
59.890427
-61.170303
59.890427
-61.170303
59.890427
-61.170303
59.890427
-61.170303
```

If anyone knows a better reliable way to get pitch, or how to fix mine please let me know!

By the way, please don't mark this as already answered unless the answer is actually working and good, or at least someone tell me how I can incorporate what I've already gotten into that, thanks.

Comment: I'm unclear what is actually being asked here.  Is `getNeededRotations()` a method you wrote?  Is it working properly or not?

Comment: `getNeededRotations()` was a provided method, it functions properly, and should be. I provided it to give context as it is not a basic java method. @markspace

Comment: There is a bit to much code for me here but you may want to look into something called quaternions. There are problems with doing yaw/pitch/roll in any language, and quaternions avoid most of the issues. They are not supported natively in java so you would probably need to import a 3rd party lib.

Comment: I'm aware of quaternions, but I've never really liked them, and my yaw calculation already works, do you at least know a quick reliable way I can get pitch?